# How to replace only first instance with grep/regex?

Tags: regex, grep-indesign

I'm trying to design a single regex that produces the two following scenarios:

```
foobar_foobar_190412_foobar_foobar.jpg  =>  190412
foobar_20190311_2372_foobar.jpg         =>  20190311
```

The regex I came up with is close, but I can't figure out how to make it only output the first number:

```
.*_(\d+)_(\d*).*                        =>  $1

foobar_foobar_190412_foobar_foobar.jpg  =>  190412
foobar_20190311_2372_foobar.jpg         =>  (no match)
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: How are you using this regex with grep?

Comment: Technically not grep. It's the GREP find/replace panel in Adobe InDesign. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `\D*(\d+).*` => `$1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
find:    \D+_(\d+)_.*
replace: $1
```

I didn't know about the "non-digit" character!

Answer (score 1):

With option `-P` (perl regex) and `-o` (only-matching):

```
grep -Po '^\D+\K\d+' file.txt
190412
20190311
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  \D+       # 1 or more non digit, you can use \D* for 0 or more non digits
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
  \d+       # 1 or more digits
```

**Edit according to missunderstanding of grep tag**

You can do:

- Find: `^\D(\d+)_.*$`
- Replace: `$1`

Comment: I'd probably use `\D*`.

Comment: @melpomene: True, I've added `*` as an option.

Comment: I can't use this. I need a regex of the form find/replace. This is being used in the InDesign grep panel.

Comment: @PatrickHennessey: So why have you tagged your question with "grep"? Grep can find a pattern but can't do replacement. What language/tool are you using? Please, edit your question and add [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366988/372239)

Answer (score 0):

if you care about the underscore matches, here is a `sed` version

```
sed -E 's/[^0-9]*_([0-9]+)_.*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score -1):

If we wish to capture the first number, we can likely use this simple expression:

```
_([0-9]+)?_
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QdVQgf/1)

or

```
.+?_([0-9]+)?_.+
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XX2PEf/1)

and replace it with `$1`.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Demo

This snippet just shows that how the capturing group works:

```js
const regex = /_([0-9]+)?_/gm;
const str = `foobar_foobar_190412_foobar_foobar.jpg
foobar_20190311_2372_foobar.jpg`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why did you make the capture group optional?

Comment: If you add `?`, it suddenly starts matching `__` instead. With either pattern you get two matches in the second line.

Comment: This doesn't work. I need the regex to replace the entire line with the output.

Comment: Why not just `/(\d+).*/g`? Then you don't have to worry about `m` or zero-width matches or accidentally matching twice in `foo_123_bar_456_baz.jpg`. But none of that helps if OP is using `grep`, not JS.

Comment: It won't work. I need a find/replace regex similar to my first post.